# I have the following view in Django REST Framework to follow a profile:

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My views.py:

```py
class FollowView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, pk):
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)
        user = request.user
        if user_profile.user == user:
            return Response({"error": "You cannot follow your own profile."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        try:
            follower = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user) 
            user_profile.follower.add(follower)
            user_profile.save()  
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response({"error": "An error occurred while trying to follow this profile."}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        return Response({"success": "You are now following this profile."}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My models.py:

```py
user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
follower= models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name= 'followed_by', blank= True, symmetrical= False)
```

However, when I make a POST request to this view, the follower relationship is not actually saved to the database. The response is successful but the profile is not followed.

What am I missing here to properly save the follower relationship?

Comment: Can you show the exact request you make?

Comment: i publish the solution as an answer, thank u Willem!

Answer (score 0):

- after long conversation with chatgpt, finally i realized that i need to serialize the post data, so here the solution:
- the view

  ```
   class FollowProfileView(generics.GenericAPIView):
       serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
       permission_classes= (IsAuthenticated,)

       def post(self, request, pk):
           user_profile = request.user.profile
           to_follow_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)

           if user_profile == to_follow_profile:
               return Response({"error": "You cannot follow your own profile."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

           user_profile.follower.add(to_follow_profile)
           return Response({"success": "You are now following this profile."}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
  ```
- the serializer:

  ```
   class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       follower = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
       class Meta:
           model = Profile
           fields = ('id', 'user', 'follower')
  ```

Comment: I don't really see where you serialize the data: you override a POST request, and that POST request returns a JSON response without any serialization. It might indeed work for a GET request to that endoint, but the logic for the POST request looks the same.